# Developing Custom Window into Class Library in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to develop Custom Window, which i can reuse in other applications.

- I know that WPF cannot derive from XAML
- I also tried to deploy it as Class Library, the code provided in this
  video:
  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EuhhL_NF-B0&feature=c4-overview&list=UUjwAVugYBMQemsMi9AD4SZA
  , but still it does not read the XAML file.
- I tried with code-behind to set the ControlTemplate, but as i read FrameworkElementFactory is deprecated...

All i want to do is, derive from Window, change the ControlTemplate, release it as Class Library... anyone can show me how or point me to the right direction?

Comment: If you google it, [this](http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/03/16/how-to-create-a-custom-window-in-wpf/) is the first link which explains how to create a custom window in WPF.

Comment: Just create a class derived from `Window` (in code) and in a `ResourceDictionary` define the default `Style` and `ControlTemplate` for that Window. Put all that in a dll and then add that resourcedictionary to `Application.Resources`, using Pack URI. What is your question?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, i found @sthotakura's answer helpful enough.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion the best solution will be to create custom UserControl, and then load it from Window.xaml.

Once you created your user control just load it from Window like this:

```
<Window xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Styx.GUI.View"  x:Class="Styx.GUI.View.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="800" Width="650" MinHeight="600" MinWidth="600">

<my:MainWindowUserControl />

</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but i want completely to customize, a window, not control

Comment: I think that if you declare your custom class solely in C# you can then make a template from that that uses that definition in XAML and C# behind file as the Standard Window does. I've been trying to figure this out myself. I'm close so if this template idea works I'll post the answer here.